# Popup QCompleter in QStyledItemDelegate immediately without text input

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QCompleter on a QTableWidget column. As soon as the user starts editing I would like the completer to pop up, not waiting for them to enter text first. I subclassed the setEditorData function of the QStyledItemDelegate to do this which seems to make the most sense to me, however when I call `completer.complete()` nothing happens until I finish editing (at which point the popup fires).

Here is my code for the delegate:

```
class CompleterItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter(['test', 'test2'])
        completer.setCompletionMode(completer.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)

        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        edit.setCompleter(completer)
        return edit

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        completer = editor.completer()
        completer.complete() # does not fire until after editing is done
        completer.popup().show() # no luck here either
        print("setting editor data") # this however does work as expected...
        super().setEditorData(editor, index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [`complete()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcompleter.html#complete) when the widget is displayed and for this you can use the [`showEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showEvent) method:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def showEvent(self, event):
        if self.completer() is not None:
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.completer().complete)
        super().showEvent(event)


class CompleterItemDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter(["test", "test2"])
        completer.setCompletionMode(QtGui.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        edit = LineEdit(parent)
        edit.setCompleter(completer)
        return edit


def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(args)

    w = QtGui.QTableWidget(4, 4)
    delegate = CompleterItemDelegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    w.show()

    ret = app.exec_()
    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Hm sadly not working for me, perhaps a bug of some kind in 4.8?

Comment: @Spencer Have you tried just my example or tried it in your project? I recommend you first try my code.

Comment: I tried your code and sometimes I do see a flicker of a box, but only for a moment. No errors or anything

Comment: Works perfectly. Clever! ;)